# Strip Pom during Publish?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I want my poms in a public facing repository to assist with transitive dependency calculation but I don't want my source control and other details included in the public poms.

Is there a standard way to strip poms to their bare essentials or would I use an xslt plugin and write a transformation to filter the content I wish to exclude?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look into [flatten-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/) which seemed to be the right direction.

Comment: Wow, and just in time.  It has pre-release stamped all over it.  Hot of the presses, my solution....   Thanks